# The image of a homomorphism on the group of $F_p$-rational points on an elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, group-homomorphism

Let $p$ be prime and let the elliptic curve $E/\mathbb F_p$ be given an affine equation
\begin{equation}
  y^2 = f(x) = (x - e_1)(x - e_2)(x - e_3), \quad e_i \in \mathbb F_p.
\end{equation}

Let the $\mathcal O$ be the unit element of $E(\mathbb F_p)$ and define the map 
\begin{equation}
\varepsilon: E(\mathbb F_p) \to \mathbb (\mathbb F_p^\times/(\mathbb F_p^\times)^2)^3: P \mapsto (\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2, \varepsilon_3)(P),
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
  \varepsilon_i: E(\mathbb F_p) \to \mathbb F_p^\times/(\mathbb F_p^\times)^2: P \mapsto \begin{cases}
    x - e_i \bmod (\mathbb F_p^\times)^2 & \text{if } \mathcal O \neq P = (x,y) \neq (\theta_i, 0),\newline
    f'(e_i) \bmod (\mathbb F_p^\times)^2 & \text{if } \mathcal O \neq P = (e_i, 0),\newline
    1 \bmod (\mathbb F_p^\times)^2 & \text{if } P = \mathcal O.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

I need to show that the image of $\varepsilon$ is 
\begin{equation}
  H := \{(1,1,1), (1, a, a), (a, 1, a), (a, a, 1)\}, \quad \text{where} \quad \mathbb F_p^\times/(\mathbb F_p^\times)^2 = \{1, a\}
\end{equation}
I know that the image of $\varepsilon$ is a subgroup of $H$, and that the kernel of $\varepsilon$ is $2E(\mathbb F_p)$. Therefore, the image of $\varepsilon$ is isomorphic to
\begin{equation}
  E(\mathbb F_p) / 2E(\mathbb F_p).
\end{equation}

Because clearly $\#E(\mathbb F_p)[2] \neq 0$, this group cannot be trivial. Hence, at least one nontrivial element of $H$ lies in the image of $\varepsilon$. However, I do not know how to show this implies the other nontrivial elements of $H$ are in the image of $\varepsilon$. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I didn't know that you would get a homomorphsim from this! Anyway, if it is a homomorphism does the claim not follow from the fact that the points $(e_i,0)$ all have order two. In other words $\#E(\Bbb{F}_p)[2]=4$ (in addition to you having proved that the kernel is exactly $2E(\Bbb{F}_p)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes it does! This is analogous to Theorem 8.14 in ``Elliptic Curves - Number Theory and Cryptography" by Washington et al. And thanks, that would work!